# Proof of $a0=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For $a\in \mathbb{R}$ I wanna prove $a0 = 0$. Proof: $a0 = a0+0 = a0 + (a + (-a))= a(0+1) + (-a) = a + (-a) = 0$.

In the first step of the proof ($ \ldots = a0+0 = \ldots$ ) I use the axiom of the neutral element $u + 0 = u$, $u\in \mathbb{R}$.  Isn't this proof wrong cause I asume that $a0$ is an Element of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not wrong: by definition, multiplication is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ we we know that $a0\in\mathbb{R}$ as long as $a,0\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. A simpler proof might be $a0 = a(0+0) = a0+a0 \Rightarrow 0 = a0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, no problem there. You can also prove as follow:

Let's first prove the following auxiliary theorem

> Theorem: $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}.$
> If $x+y = x+z$, then $y=z$

Proof. Assume $x+y = x+z$ holds for all $x$, $y$, and $z$.
 $y=0+y=((-x)+x)+y=(-x)+(x+y)=(-x)+(x+z) = ((-x)+x)+z = 0+z=z.$$\blacksquare$
Now using this theorem, we can prove $a0=0.$

$a0 + a0 = a(0+0)=a0=a0+0.$ 
$a0+a0 = a0+0$  
$a0=0.$ $\blacksquare$